# Retrieve data from WrappedArray in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I Have the following simple program, and I don't know how to read values rapped inside an array in Scala.

```
val all_marks = Result.groupBy("class", "school").agg(collect_list("mark") as "marks",count("*") as "cnt").where($"cnt" > 10)

var mrk=all_marks.collect().map(mark=>""+mark(2))
```

The results appear like this:

```
mrk: Array[String] = Array(WrappedArray(52.0, 18.0, 17.0, 36.0, 22.0, 22.0), WrappedArray(49.0, 53.0, 41.0, 30.0, 48.0, 36.0))
```

I need to iterate the (mrk) array to read each WrappedArray separately, for further mathematical calculation on each mark in each WrappedArray. How to read each WrappedArray in a simple way.

Comment: Did you try using `mrk.foreach`? Also, `.map(mark => mark(2).toString)` .

Comment: I tried for(e <- mrk){ val d=e.toDouble}. But an error has occurred of "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "WrappedArray"

Comment: Yes I tried .map(mark => mark(2).toString), but this method doesn't change the marks to double

Comment: `for( e <- mrk)` what you get after this is `WrappedArray`. You have to loop over that WrappedArray again. You just want to convert whatever is inside WrappedArray to Double?

Comment: Yes correct, I need to convert it to double, then sort the marks in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace var mrk=all_marks.collect().map(mark=>""+mark(2)) with

```
val mrk=all.select("marks")
```

then convert the dataframe to rdd(list), and then back to dataframe

```
toRDD=mrk.rdd.map(_.getList[Int](0).toList).toDF("marks")
```

then define UDF

```
 var i=0
    var read_row_by_row=""
//define udf
    val createUdf = udf((list: Seq[Int]) => {
      val ascending = list.sorted  //sorts in ascending order
//in this loop you can add whatever you like of calculations      
for (i <- 0 to ascending.size - 1){
      read_row_by_row=read_row_by_row+","+ascending(i)
      }

      s"${read_row_by_row}"
    })
    val g =ag_two.withColumn("mark", createUdf($"marks"))
    g.show
+--------------------+
|               marks|
+--------------------+
|,17,17,17,17,18,1...|
|,18,18,18,18,19,1...|
|,18,23,24,24,24,2...|
|,18,23,24,24,24,2...|
|,17,18,18,18,18,1...|
|,25,35,36,39,41,4...|
|,25,35,36,39,41,4...|
|,31,31,33,33,33,3...|
```